# Segmentation Fault in array of arrays depending on size

Tags: arrays, c

I have code that loads text into an array of char arrays `char var [size_x][100]`, if the one dimension (in this case `size_x`) gets above a certain threshold (around 1mln), I get a segmentation fault, which I do not understand.

As I am not that experienced with C, I was wondering if someone can enlighten me why this throws an error.

Any help is much appreciated!

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int size_x = 10000; // works
  //int size_x = 1000000; // segmentation fault
  char arr[size_x][100];
  char var[] = "hello world";

  memcpy(&arr[0], &var, sizeof(var));
  printf("var: '%s'\n", arr[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allocating large thing on the stack and causing stack overflow.

To allocate large things dynamically, you should use the heap (`malloc()` family).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int size_x = 10000;
  //int size_x = 1000000;
  char (*arr)[100] = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * size_x);
  char var[] = "hello world";

  memcpy(&arr[0], &var, sizeof(var));
  printf("var: '%s'\n", arr[0]);
  free(arr);
  return 0;
}
```